# Embedding Twitter Timeline Widget shows only a link to twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I try to embedd some twitter timelines to a start page of a simple app. But all I get after nesting the widget code from https://publish.twitter.com/ in my html code, is a link to that twitter account.

```
<div>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-width="500" data-height="250" href="https://twitter.com/freudeamkochen?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by freudeamkochen</a>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
</div>
```

I use it in a symfony project on a local XAMPP dev stage - maybe this is a problem? Any other idea, what's missing?

Comment: Code as shown works perfectly fine by itself, https://jsfiddle.net/dk57tv8o/ _“on a local XAMPP dev stage - maybe this is a problem?”_ - shouldn’t be. Do you get  any error message in browser console regarding this?

Comment: Thank you misorude - your example on jsfiddle stepped me forward. I saw only a link there too. So I tried another browser and voíla I can see a timeline. I have to figure out, why firefox didn't show up that embedded element, although all adblocker are disabled.

Comment: Got it. Firefox is active blocking Twitter services if option "Content Blocking" (formerly Tracking Protection) is enabled and set to "all". Then I tried to enable my Adblocker and same here - Twitter ist blocked due to Tracking Protection. For I don't know the settings of user browser, I have to find another way for displaying such information. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for all those, who have the same trouble:

Got it. Firefox is active blocking Twitter services if option "Content Blocking" (formerly Tracking Protection) is enabled and set to "all". Then I tried to enable my Adblocker and same here - Twitter ist blocked due to Tracking Protection. For I don't know the settings of user browser, I have to find another way for displaying such information

Thanks to misorude for giving the matching hint!

Comment: You can click the blue shield in the URL bar to disable Enhanced Tracking Protection for the site. I don't think you want to get around this - it's a feature. Twitter's tracking is the problem.